# To test if sequence is convergent

Tags: sequences-and-series

Given sequence is $<1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4}...>$

Now the terms of sequence are decreasing and their magnitude is also decreasing. I have intuitive feel that this sequence is converging to $0$. But i am not sure.

Thanks

Comment: It converges to 0. You can use the definition for proving.

Comment: Can you show that the sequence $1,\frac12,\frac13,\frac14,\ldots$ converges to $0$?

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Yes but this is alternating

Comment: @SophieClad We have to show that for each $\varepsilon>0$, there exists $N\ge1$ such that $$\biggl|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}n-0\biggr|<\varepsilon$$ when $n>N$. But we have that $|(-1)^{n+1}/n|\le1/n$ and $1/n$ goes to $0$ as $n\to\infty$.

Comment: @Cm7F7Bb Oh yes  Thanks

Comment: You could write this as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

By the definition of convergence, a sequence $(x_n)$ converges to $x_0$ if given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N_0\in \mathbb N$ (the value of $N_0$ depends on $\epsilon$) such that $|x_n-x_0|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge N_0$.

We can show that $(x_n)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as follows.

Let any $\epsilon>0$ be given.

Then,
$$|x_n-x_0|=\left|\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n}-0\right|=\frac{1}{n}$$

By the Archimedean property, given any $\epsilon>0$, there exists an $N_0\in\mathbb N$ such that $\frac{1}{N_0}<\epsilon$.

Thus, for all $n\ge N_0$, 
$$|x_n-x_0|=\frac{1}{n}\le\frac{1}{N_0}<\epsilon$$

Hence, $(x_n)=\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} \rightarrow 0$ as $n\rightarrow\infty$

Answer (score 0):

Note that the sequence $<1,-\frac{1}{2},\frac{1}{3},-\frac{1}{4}...>$ is the difference between $<1,0,\frac{1}{3},0, \frac{1}{5}...>$ and $<0,\frac{1}{2},0,\frac{1}{4},0...>$ which are two sequences that converge to $0$. (I guess you can do that for these two.)

Comment: And use sandwich theorem. Thanks